# How to ensure only once instance of an Azure web-job is running at any time

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

I've got a continuously running WebJob on my auto-scale Azure website.

My WebJob is a simple console application with a while(true) loop that subscribes to certain messages on the Azure service bus and processes them. I don't want to process the same message twice, so when the web site is scaled an another WebJob is started I need for it to detect that another instance is already running and just sit there doing nothing until it's either killed (by scaling down again) or the other instance is killed. In the last scenario the second WebJob should detect that's the other is no longer take over.

Any takers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a queue (either using the Service Bus or storage queues) and pull the jobs off (create and manage a lease to the message) and process them from there. If that lease is managed properly, the job should only get processed once although you should make sure it's idempotent just in case as there are fringe cases where it will be processed more than once.

Comment: I have other processes subscribing to the same messages as the WebJob. That's why I use a bus instead of a queue. Several processes are to receive the message, but only one instance of the WebJob.

Comment: There are two types of queues in Windows Azure, Azure Storage Queues, and Service Bus Queues (this includes topics which are built on top of queues). As Jaxidian points out, as long as you're properly managing the lease on the queue message, you shouldn't have an issue.

Comment: @Paaland: Are you using a Topic with multiple Subscriptions (i.e. pub/sub)? If so, then take one of those subscriptions and do nothing other than move those messages into a bonefide queue and then have your worker app process these messages from the queue (storage queues or service bus queues will work). Have a read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh367516.aspx

Comment: @Jaxidian: Thank you. I did not think of that. I basically have one publisher and multiple subscribers. If I let the publisher publish both to the bus and a queue I can let the WebJobs use the queue ensuring the even if multiple WebJob instances are running any one message is handled by only one instance.